# Using 'default' as a variable

Tags: java, android

Hello I have an object that has the value "default". But I can't do it because it gives error: Identifier expected.I receive this object from a service and I cannot modify the values.
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/node#default

private String default;
or 
private Boolean default;

I want to do getter and setter.

Any way to solve?

Comment: default is a reserved keyword, you can't use it for something it's not intended for, like for a variable name.

Comment: Do you get JSON from service? As default is a keyword, you can not use as variable-name. You need to find ulternatives.

Comment: Just use a different variable name

Answer (score 0):

It can't be solved, because it's not a problem. It's a rule. You can't use a keyword as a variable name.
what do you mean by **"I receive this object from a service and I cannot modify the values."**.
you are getting a json object, right?. Just parse it to a different variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue where I needed to use the 'default' and 'ref' as class members in order to create objects because the server would require this format. I got no solution to define members with these name, so I ended up creating a list that would create static strings as **required (with default and ref in them)** based on conditions (parameters passed while creating objects).

This is a work around to live with in case you cannot get the other side to stop using these names.